# 301 redirect not working for page ending in /

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to set up a 301 redirect a WordPress page ending in / to a .php page on my site. I've tried this:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.mydomain.com/blog/old-page/ http://www.mydomain.com/new-page.php
```

After searching this site I also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.mydomain.com/blog/old-page/‎$ http://www.mydomain.com/new-page.php [R=301,L]
```

Neither one works. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remember that `RewriteRule` only matches URI after first slash, it doesn't match full URL with domain or query string etc.**

Change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^old-page/?‎$ /new-page.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I was actually editing the htaccess file in the /blog folder, but from what you write it sounds like I need to edit the htaccess file in the root instead - is that right?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite follow: Won't that direct the visitor to the URL blog/new-page.php instead of the correct URL which is mydomain.com/new-page.php?

Comment: No since I used `/new-page.php` **with a slash** it will redirect to `mydomain.com/new-page.php`